# Enabling specifics Triggers, Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I’m in a situation where i have to disable all my triggers and enable them in order to accelerate a specific job of backup.
i use the code below the disable all my triggers

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL"
GO
```

I kept a table `#InitiallyDesabledTR(object_ID, Name)` with the object_id and the name of all my triggers that are initially disabled.

```
Create Table #InitiallyDesabledTR(Object_id int, name varchar (45))
Insert into #InitiallyDesabledTR(Object_id, name)
(
    SELECT object_id, name
    FROM sys.triggers tr
    WHERE tr.is_disabled = 1

    )
```

Did any one have an idea on how could i re-enable all my triggers present in my database  except those present on my temporary table `#InitiallyDesabledTR`.

Comment: Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will disable all of your table triggers that are not already disabled, and then re-enable only the ones that you disabled. Tested in SQL Server 2008 R2.  Instead of using a temp table to keep track of the triggers that were initially disabled, I changed to use a physical table, `dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable`, to track the triggers that were disabled as part of your job.  This ensures that if the job failed for some reason AFTER the triggers were disabled but BEFORE they were re-enabled, then you still have a list of the triggers that still need to be re-enabled and those triggers would be re-enabled on the next run.  With the original setup, if you disabled all of the triggers, and then there was an error during your backup job processing, then all triggers would remain disabled, and you would lose your reference to the triggers that were originally disabled because the temp table, `#InitiallyDesabledTR`, would be gone.

Setups: creates a table `dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable`, and 2 stored procedures `dbo.spDbAdmin_DisableAllTableTriggers` and `dbo.spDbAdmin_ReEnableTriggers`

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables t where t.name = 'dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable')
    create table dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable(
        object_id int not null, 
        parent_id int not null, 
        triggerName sysname not null, 
        tableSchemaName sysname not null, 
        tableName sysname not null,
        creationdate datetime
        , constraint PK_dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (object_id)
    );
go

CREATE PROC dbo.spDbAdmin_DisableAllTableTriggers
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable(object_id, parent_id, triggerName, tableSchemaName, tableName, creationdate)
    SELECT tr.object_id, tr.parent_id, tr.name AS triggerName, schema_name(tbl.schema_id) as tableSchemaName, tbl.name as tableName, getdate() as creationdate
    FROM sys.triggers tr
        INNER JOIN sys.tables tbl on tbl.object_id = tr.parent_id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable e on tr.object_id = e.object_id 
    WHERE tr.is_disabled = 0
        AND e.object_id is null --not already in the table
    ;

    --disable all triggers
    EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'

END
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.spDbAdmin_ReEnableTriggers
AS
BEGIN
    declare @object_id int, @schemaName nvarchar(256), @tableName nvarchar(256), @triggerName nvarchar(3000), @sql nvarchar(max);

    select @object_id = min(e.object_id) from dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable e;

    while exists(select 1 from dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable)
    begin
        select @schemaName = t.tableSchemaName, @tableName = t.tableName, @triggerName = t.triggerName
        from dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable t
        where t.object_id = @object_id
        ;

        set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' ENABLE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(@triggerName) ;

        EXEC(@sql);

        delete t from dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable t where t.object_id = @object_id;
        select @object_id = min(t.object_id) from dbo.dbAdmin_TriggersToReEnable t;
    end;

END
GO
```

And then you could setup a SQL Agent job with the following steps:

```
--Step 1
EXEC dbo.spDbAdmin_DisableAllTableTriggers;

--Step 2
--....do your backup job work here...

--Step 3
EXEC dbo.spDbAdmin_ReEnableTriggers;
```

Comment: That's exactly what i need.
I have to update the code in order to make possible the enabling and disabling triggers in all the database.
in fact, i have to inable all the triggers, non clustred indexes, and constraints to make my specific backup of near than 100G of data possible in a brief delay.

Comment: Just curious, why are the triggers being disabled for the purpose of the backup?  I'm surprised that this would impact the backup time. If any data modifications are made while the backup job is running, then none of the triggers will function, which could cause data issues.

Answer (score 0):

i have to disable all my indexes, triggers, and constraints to speed up my back up.
And even with such action, this back up takes more than 15 hours by executing near to 900 line of code.
I didn't have the possibility to make a drop with cascade, that's why i had to check all the integrity between an initial table and all her instances.
ps. my only criteria of this backup is the date of creation of an order.

Comment: So this is not a SQL Server backup (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx), but a job that runs that does a "backup" of data by inserting (and deleting it sounds like if referential constraints are an issue) data based on order creation date?

Comment: Data based Backup (deleting all the order created before 2013)
I have more than 120G of data and more than 450 Tables in my database + 477 Views ...
Imagine the job that i had to do ...
but the good news is that the script is done ands the first test seems good